# symfony can't call any module. config?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I set up another computer (Linux Mint 12). I can call in a browser the index of my project very well with and without frontend_dev.php. But I can not call any module. It is saying the file does not exist. Any idea?

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias dev.project.com
 DocumentRoot /home/trunk/web
 DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
 Alias /sf "/home/trunk/symfony/data/web/sf"

<Directory /home/trunk/web>
AllowOverride All    
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI    
Order allow,deny    
Allow from all    
</Directory>

<Directory /home/trunk/symfony/data/web/sf">
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /home/trunk/symfony">
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The debug backtrace would be helpful in this instance (hence downvote)

Comment: How can I see it? What do you mean backtrace?

Comment: Is it a 404 from the webserver, or a Symfony exception? If it's a Symfony exception, you'll get a backtrace on the dev controller (or a controller with debug enabled). If it's a webserver 404 then something else is awry

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /frontend_dev.php/aboutus/b2b was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at dev.tolisto.de Port 80

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments above, the problem lies your webserver. I would check that:

- Your Apache config is set to allow Path Info stuff (`AcceptPathInfo` is set to something other than `Off`). Try `On` if it's set to `Default`
- Your Apache config is set to allow .htaccess files (check the `AllowOverride` is not set to `None` and `AccessFileName` is set to `.htaccess`)
- You have mod_rewrite enabled in your Apache build (try removing the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` bits from your .htaccess. If mod_rewrite doesn't exist, Apache will throw a 500 error)

Comment: Yep, this is almost certainly an htaccess issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache as web server ?

Did you setup it [as the doc says](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration#chapter_05_sub_web_server_configuration) ?

And what about [the `.htaccess`](http://svn.jobeet.org/trunk/web/.htaccess) ?

Comment: Yes I am using Apache as a webserver. My .htaccess: Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]
  # we check if the .html
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # no, so we redirect to our f. web cont.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>